# PHP: How do I get the milestone version of composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I need to get the milestone version of composer, i.e. `alpha7` or `alpha8`. But the `--version` flag only provides the git commit:

```
# composer --version
Composer version a8adbfeb9fc7861deade782938222714168a22a8 2014-09-05 16:28:50
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, with the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could specify version while install

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin --version=1.0.0-alpha8
./composer.phar --version
```

Or you could install source of composer.

```
https://github.com/composer/composer#installation-from-source
```